# Glass is Gray due to Low Light Transmission Values

Tags: rendering, glass

I rendered an image of this 3d logo a day ago. It appears like this:
[image: (Screenshot of it)]

I have modified my blender file since then, and have this weird issue now where the shadow of the glass is offset and the lighting makes the glass look gray.
[image: (Screenshot of it)]
I don't know what I did to cause this, nor do I have any way of restoring the previous project file. I've already tried that.

[image]
*The .blend file is no longer available for download.*

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The glass is getting dark, because you do not have enough transmission bounces. You can set them in the Properties Editor, Render tab, under Light Paths panel, Max Bounces subpanel. You should increase total as well as Transmission bounces. 32 works but is more than needed so if you wanted it more efficient you could increase them gradually to test what's the smallest amount that is enough.

[image]

Comment: In Blender 2.79, these settings are located in the rendering settings in the side panel.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Download button is located at the center of the page for current Blender version: https://www.blender.org/download/

Comment: I don't like modern blender too much. 2.79 is easier to use in my opinion.

Comment: I recommend upgrading to current or at least more recent version. It is superior ir pretty much every way. It will even likely render a lot faster.

Answer (score -1):

In order to get rid of the gray-ish tint on the glass, you must increase the value of the transmission bounces property. In Blender 2.79, these settings are located in the rendering settings under the Light Paths category in the properties panel. In later versions of Blender, they can be found in the same spot, but look a slight bit different. For my model, 18 as the Max Bounce & Transmission value worked fine.

Thanks to @Martynas Žiemys for the Original Answer!

Comment: Note that there is [nothing called "the side panel" in Blender 2.79](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/interface/window_system/introduction.html#components-of-an-editor). The closest term to "Side-anything" would probably be [the Sidebar](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/regions.html) - that as we see in the docs used to be called Properties Region and is still unofficially called 'n-panel'. You are probably referring to Properties editor. It's wrong to call it a side panel, because it doesn't need to be on the side of anything - it can be anywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer is good for. The only real information in here is that it is found under "Light Paths" (which is stated in the original answer as well) and that it looks "slight bit different" - but you don't show how different. That some options might look different in general should be clear to everyone who is using such an outdated version and sees some of the newer screenshots in many of the questions/answers here...

Comment: I really don't understand what other info there is to learn from this post. What I wrote is the only info I needed to use to solve the issue. And by the way, saying that the properties in later versions of Blender look a slight bit different makes complete sense. Saying later versions of Blender does not mean versions before the current or 2.79. It means every release after 2.79 up until the latest version.